# Sending both text and html formatted emails via smtplib, python

Tags: python, html, email, smtplib

I was trying ti send both text and html element via the smtplib in python, but there i came across a issue, when i am using the attach function to the message on the latest attach is being sent in the mail, not all of them. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

OUTPUT I RECEIVE : [image: IMAGE HERE]

Here the html is getting received **not** the normal text and I want both of them.

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "me@gmail.com"
you = "you@gmail.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')


msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

mail.ehlo()

mail.starttls()

mail.login(me, "pass")
mail.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
mail.quit()
```

Comment: If a Mail User Agent (MUA) can render the HTML part of the email, then it won't show the text. Click on the "three dots" at the top-right corner and click "Show Original". That displays email in the raw form it was received. You should see the text part there.

Comment: I read that by default mail clients will only show the last attachment, unless it's in a format they can't render. To render the plain text by default, attach that one second (i.e. swap the part 1 and 2 in the msg.attach() lines).